# find-an-entity library is not compatible with Angular Ivy - Angular 16

Tags: angular, migration, angular15, angular16

I am getting error related to `find-an-entity` package. Below is the error:

```
Error: src/app/pages/ratings-reviews/ratings-reviews.module.ts:11:5 - error NG6002: 'FindAnEntityModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

11     FindAnEntityModule
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/find-an-entity/lib/find-an-entity.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class FindAnEntityModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (find-an-entity) which declares FindAnEntityModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

Here is the version: `"find-an-entity": "^0.1.0"`

I am migrating from `Angular 15 to 16` and facing the issue. I could not find the compatible version for that package for Angular 16. What can be the solution for that?

Comment: I have several of packages which are not compatible with ivy engine are not working
and giving error. it seem we need to go to latest of all version where ivy may support